# PayPal mobile SDK, chained payments

Tags: ios, mobile, paypal, sdk

As I found on the website concerning PayPal Mobile SDK chained payments are not yet supported there. It is suggested to use old MPL.

Is it already known about when the chained payments will be available in Mobile SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no known ETA at this time. They first would need to be implemented into the REST APIs and can then be prioritized for the mSDK.